# Faster/Better way to modify (tuple defined) parts of a Numpy array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy pixel array (either 0 or 255), using .where I pull the tuples of where it is > 0. I now want to use those tuples to add 1 to a separate 2D numpy array. Is the best way to just use a for loop as shown below or is there a better numpy-like way?

```
changedtuples = np.where(imageasarray > 0)

#If there's too much movement change nothing.
if frame_size[0]*frame_size[1]/2 < changedtuples[0].size:
    print "No change- too much movement."
elif changedtuples[0].size == 0:
    print "No movement detected."
else:
    for x in xrange(changedtuples[0].size):
        movearray[changedtuples[1][x],changedtuples[0][x]] = movearray[changedtuples[1][x],changedtuples[0][x]]+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
movearray[imageasarray.T > 0] += 1
```

`where` is redundant. You can index an array with a boolean mask, like that produced by `imageasarray.T > 0`, to select all array cells where the mask has a True. The `+=` then adds 1 to all those cells. Finally, the `T` is a transpose, since it looks like you're switching the indices around when you increment the cells of `movearray`.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. If I remove the `where` I can still check for no movement with `all` but how do I check the first condition, if over 50% (or whatever threshold) is greater than 0 to disregard the movement?

Comment: @DTC: Save the mask, so you don't have to compute it twice (`mask = imageasarray.T > 0`). Then, `mask.sum()` is the number of True entries.